# Подключение интернет-магазина к платежным системам

Tags: интернет-магазин

Добрый день! Практически сделал свой первый интернет-магазин, все работает отлично. Но остается такой вопрос, как подключать интернет-магазин к платежным системам, чтобы пользователь мог оплатить за товары через карту? В интернете искал, что-то внятных ответов не нашел, только муть про регистрацию и оформление кучи документов каких-то. Обращаюсь прежде всего к тем, кто уже прошел этот путь и создавал интернет-магазины, знает как сделать подключение к платежным системам. И к каким рекомендуете подключаться системам. Ответьте, пожалуйста! Поделитесь опытом!

Answer (score 3):

Есть ресурсы, которые позволяют комплексно подойти к оплате: дают свою API, а все остальное - их заботы (например [Robokassa](http://robokassa.ru/ru/)).

P.S. Они требуют ИП и ИНП.

Comment: а примеры подлючения к робокассе есть где-нибудь? Я имею ввиду код на php. И насчет ИП и ИНП - это документы юридические я так понимаю, а без них нельзя как-нибудь опробовать механизм работы с платежными системами?

Comment: как правило, любая серьезная платежная система имеет так называемую песочницу, которая и позволяет настроить подключение и опробовать ее.

Comment: Робокасса дает готовый код, там всего-то 5 или 6 методов.
Документация по всем методам есть, ну и "песочница" само-собой.
Но как только вы выйдете на "боевой" режим, "песочница" станет недоступной.

http://robokassa.ru/ru/HowTo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Подключайте платежный агрегатор - мороки меньше, сразу убьете одним ударом кучу зайцев: и банковские карты, и Яндекс.Деньги, и QIWI принимать сможете. В качестве дополнения к ответу dekameron посоветую *Net Pay*.